# salto de pagina html pone lenta la impresión a pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

Espero me puedan ayudar con los siguiente.

Tengo una vista en html el cual al presionar windows + p puedo imprimirlo en pdf.

Pero sucede lo siguiente, al hacer eso la vista previa de la impresión a pdf se demora demaciado no segundos, minutos.

Estuve viendo un poco y me di cuenta que este error me lo esta generando el salto de pagina, ya que si lo quito, imprime el pdf en segundos (como normalmente deberia de ser)

estoy usando el siguiente código para el sato de página

```
     .page_break {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
```

y coloco esto donde quiero el salto página

ahora bien me consulta seria, estoy ocupando la manera correcta para crear saltos de página?  hay una mejor alternativa?

Acabo de realizar una prueba con el navegador Firefox y este se imprime con normalidad (con el salto de pagina), seria solamente con Google Chrome

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿solo te pasa con tus documentos con ese atributo? Lo digo porque quizas el problema esta en el driver que convierte a PDF en lugar de tu documento en si. Tendrias que encontrar algun otro que tambien lo tenga y probar. Pero vamos, tal como dices, es un problema de Crhome seguramente, no tuyo. En mis saltos de pagina le agrego un display:block; a ese estilo, pero son tablas normalmente, y no me pasa nada de eso.

Comment: pues si solo con esos documentos me sucede y solo con chrome, para resolver por los momentos lo dejé que se tenga que imprimir con firefox mientras encuentro una solución

Answer (score 0):

Luego de buscar un poco encontré que el navegador chrome no admite page-break y que no se recomienda usarlo.

En el foro en ingles encontré una solución, la que usé fue poner todo en tabs

```
html, body, .main-content, .tabs, .tabbed-content { float: none; }

.tab {
    display: block; /* unhide all tabs */
    break-before: always;
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

aqui el enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303178/page-break-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome